# Installing scipy in cygwin

Tags: python, scipy, cygwin

I'm failing to install scipy in cygwin (32-bit) with any method I've tried (pip, direct source code). Here is the error I get

```
from scipy/spatial/ckdtree/src/ckdtree_globals.cxx:9:
    /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1629:1: warning: ‘int _import_array()’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
     _import_array(void)
     ^
    error: Command "g++ -fno-strict-aliasing -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python-2.7.10-1.i686/build=/usr/src/debug/python-2.7.10-1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/usr/src/ports/python/python-2.7.10-1.i686/src/Python-2.7.10=/usr/src/debug/python-2.7.10-1 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -Iscipy/spatial/ckdtree/src -I/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c scipy/spatial/ckdtree/src/ckdtree_globals.cxx -o build/temp.cygwin-2.2.0-i686-2.7/scipy/spatial/ckdtree/src/ckdtree_globals.o" failed with exit status 1
```

There are also a lot of warnings before this. What's the right way to have scipy on cygwin. I also looked at the official scipy website http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/windows.html but I found it a little hard to follow. However, I'm willing to try that if is the easiest way and is still works today.

Answer (score 3):

I'm getting the exact same error on scipy 0.16.0 in 64bit cygwin.

Installing 0.15.0 works for me however:

```
$ pip install scipy==0.15.0
```

Sort of annoying but probably a reasonable solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to download the C++ for Python from http://aka.ms/vcpython27, install it and try again.

I actually like the distributions from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying for the last few days myself. But as to gt6989b's answer, from pythonlibs website:

"The binaries are compatible with the official CPython distribution on Windows >=6.0. Chances are they don't work with custom Python distributions included with Blender, Maya, ArcGIS, OSGeo4W, ABAQUS, Cygwin, Pythonxy, Canopy, EPD, Anaconda, WinPython etc. Many binaries are not compatible with Windows XP or Wine."